# What is this machine/instrument in Fargo?

Tags: fargo-tv

This is from the [first](http://fargo.wikia.com/wiki/The_Crocodile%27s_Dilemma) episode of season 1 of Fargo.

At the very end of the episode Molly is having a conversation with Lou (her dad) while they are unloading some instruments from the back of their van. The conversation implies that they are there for fishing.

What is the instrument/machine Lou is handing over to Molly?

Here are some pictures. The machine is at the bottom-left corner of the first picture.

[image: instrument on the bottom left corner]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be an ice fishing drill or an Ice Auger. It's used to drill a vertical hole in thick ice to ice fish.

[image]